# Save inline attachment in EWS In C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, email-attachments

I’m developing app which integrates with our company’s exchange server and gets a shared email contents.

Problem is I could handle getting item attachments and file attachment but some of our clients sends us inline attachments inside the body of the email .. how to get those attachments and save them on a local path in c# ??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able just to process the Inline Attachment from the Message Attachment collection using the fileattachment class. If they aren't there then you can try getting the MimeContent of the message and process them using the MimeContent using a Mime library to parse it.

Problem is usually if you try to process all inline attachment you find most of them associated with email signatures etc.